# Why does the event handler throws an error in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, events

The following snippet works fine in the Google Chrome browser, but if I run it in Firefox it throws an error saying `event is not defined`.
What causes this problem?

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(event.target.id)
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: You haven't named the `event` that is implicitly passed to the handler.

Comment: @connexo — That's because they are using the non-standard global one instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global variable `event` is non-standard and Firefox does not support it.

Access the event object through the standard method (the first argument to the event handler) instead.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id)
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
```